# how to make notification or reminder based on the specific field from wpforms entries in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wpforms

The problem is wpforms has a notification built in function but it is email notifications. i want the notification bar that displays in wordpress page instead of receiving email notification.

I have tried many plugins in wordpress but mostly they can triggers the wpform when the user has submitted the form. i want the notification triggers when the date field is almost expired before 7 days. (sorry for my bad english)